# PyQt GridLayout combining widgets

Tags: pyqt

so for example, I have a GUI that has a `label1`+`line_edit1`, `label2`+`line_edit2`, `button1`, `button2`, `button3`. In a normal sense the code would look somewhat like this:

```
class gridlayout_example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.grid_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        self.label1 = QtGui.QLabel("label1")
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.label1,0,0,1,3)

        self.line_edit1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.line_edit1,1,0,1,3)

        self.label2 = QtGui.QLabel("label2")
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.label1,2,0,1,3)

        self.line_edit2 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.line_edit2,3,0,1,3)

        self.button1 = QtGui.QPushButton("button1")
        self.button2 = QtGui.QPushButton("button2")
        self.button3 = QtGui.QPushButton("button3")

        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.button1, 4,0,1,1)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.button2, 4,1,1,1)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.button3, 4,2,1,1)

        self.setLayout(self.grid_layout)
```

But is there a way to combine `label1`+`line_edit1` and `label2` + `line_edit2` so it becomes something like:

```
[label1                    
 line edit1               ] -> (0,0,1,3)
[label2                    
 line edit2               ] -> (1,0,1,3)
[button1][button2][button3] -> (2,x,1,1)
```

so basically label1+line edit1 would occupy row 0 of the grid layout, label2 + line edit2 occupy row1 and so on...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a second layout to use as a sublayout, add your widgets to it, and use [`addLayout()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#addLayout) in place of `addWidget()`

```
class gridlayout_example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(gridlayout_example, self).__init__(parent)

        label1 = QtGui.QLabel('label 1')
        line_edit1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        sublayout1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        sublayout1.addWidget(label1)
        sublayout1.addWidget(line_edit1)

        label2 = QtGui.QLabel('label 2')
        line_edit2 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        sublayout2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        sublayout2.addWidget(label2)
        sublayout2.addWidget(line_edit2)

        button1 = QtGui.QPushButton("button1")
        button2 = QtGui.QPushButton("button2")
        button3 = QtGui.QPushButton("button3")

        grid_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        grid_layout.addLayout(sublayout1, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        grid_layout.addLayout(sublayout2, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        grid_layout.addWidget(button1, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        grid_layout.addWidget(button2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        grid_layout.addWidget(button3, 2, 2, 1, 1)
```

Comment: could you show me what it would look like with the example code I wrote?

Comment: I've added an example